# Invalid use of incomplete type "struct students" and forward declaration

Tags: c++

i have a problem with my program when it compiles. I tried to figure out for like 3-4 hours and still didn't find out how to fix it. The final result is that i want to use `struct students` in multiple .cpp files without getting the error with multiple definition of.. Can you guys please help me ? Here's the code:

student.h

```
#ifndef STUDENT
#define STUDENT
#include <string>
using namespace std;

extern int var;

struct students {
    char CodSt[20];
    string NumeSt;
    string PrenSt;
    string DenDisc1;
    string MedCD1;
    string DenDisc2;
    string MedCD2;
    string DenDisc3;
    string MedCD3;
};

#endif
```

getStudents.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int var = 0;

extern struct students *student;

void getStudents() {
    int i = 0;
    ifstream ifs("Curenta.txt");
    while(!ifs.eof()) {
        ifs >> student[i].CodSt >> student[i].NumeSt >> student[i].PrenSt >> student[i].DenDisc1
            >> student[i].MedCD1 >> student[i].DenDisc2 >> student[i].MedCD2 >> student[i].DenDisc3
            >> student[i].MedCD3;
        if(!ifs.eof()) {
            i++;
        }
        var = i;
    }
    ifs.close();
}
```

Compiler error:

```
In function 'void getStudents()':
[Error] invalid use of incomplete type 'struct students'
[Error] forward declaration of 'struct students'

and same, so on..
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need `#include "student.h"`

Comment: `extern struct students` only tells the compiler that there is a struct called `students`, but says nothing about what the struct contains. You need to include the header for that.

Comment: now when i run the code, it crashes ..

Comment: You never define `student`, so this code won't compile, much less crash.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.  It's especially pernicious in header files, as you now inflict the problem on every source file that includes the header!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your `struct students` you should `#include "student.h"` file into your `.cpp` file. What that does is it causes the pre-compiler to "insert" the header file into your source code file, thus providing the correct definition of the `struct`.

A few side notes about your code (call me pedantic, but it would help you in a long run if you learn these rules early on):

- Be consistent in your naming. Your `struct` is named `students' (plural) but the include file is 'student.h' (singular)
- Do not use `using namespace ...` in your include files. The reason is: what if someone (even you a year from now, when you've forgotten the implementation details of this file) has a different `string` class with similar semantics but **not** from the standard library? If such a user includes that `students.h` file, then "suddenly" all the custom `string`s become the ones pulled from standard library, ensuring days of fun debugging :)
- It is unclear why would you have an `extern struct students * student;` line in your `.cpp` file. Either it is a mistake, or (if not) it would be a good idea to provide a short comment explaining why do you need this line

Comment: Solved .Thanks for attention, in future i will try to cover your warnings.

Comment: People on SO often skip the comments section and navigate based on votes and "marked as answer", which makes this site so great. Feel free to follow the established practice to help other users get the most informative experience when visiting your question